# Вопрос по полиморфизму. Класс А наследуется от B . перед тем как отработает класс А , отрабатывает класс B?

Tags: java, android, ооп

``Вот класс `А` имеет переопределенный метод из класса `B`. После отработки конструктора класса `А` срабатывает сразу этот переопределенный метод, хоть я его в конструкторе и не вызывал. Как `onCreate`. Допустим `onCreate` и есть тот самый переопределенный метод.  Теперь смотрим что происходит под капотом : сперва отрабатывает конструктор класса `B` , метод `onCreate` наверно там и прописан, он тоже сработал, потом срабатывает конструктор класса `А` , а потом всё то что добавлено в `onCreate` путем переопределения.
   Сейчас уже понимаю что `onCreate` не мог сработать после конструктора класса `B` , так как он переопределением может быть опустошен от того что в нем изначально было (а так может быть? в оригинальном `onCreate`, что то выполняется, а тут я его переопределил и теперь он ничего не выполняет или переопределение только для того чтобы что то добавить?) и потому что не спроста пишут `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` это ведь как раз чтобы отработал onCreate у предка с таким вот параметром переданным. Но тогда почему `onCreate` срабатывает в классе `А` сам по себе ?

Наведите порядок в моих мыслях пожалуйста.

**UPD**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  MainActivity(){
       System.out.println("конструктор ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       System.out.println("  onCreate ");

    }
}
```

Comment: тот случай когда вместо 150 слов проще привести 15 строк кода и будет понятнее

Comment: а тут код не нужен. если коротко , почему метод onCreate ,который я могу переопределить , если наследуюсь от Activity, вызывается сам по себе? Вернее что заставляет его вызываться сразу же после конструктора?

Comment: То, что вы описали в вопросе, никак само по себе не вызывается. А вот метод onCreate является служебным и вызывается в недрах самого Activity в конструкторе у класса `B` (который и есть Activity как я понял). Такой код вызовет Ваш метод без труда `public B() { onCreate(); }` в классе `A` переопределенный. Хотя обычно там не методы, а события по которым вызывается метод, но не суть важно.

Comment: Если onCreate вызывается в конструкторе Activity, то почему он вызывается еще и у меня в классе после моего конструктора? Наличие  onCreate в конструкторе Activity не является ведь причиной по которой он вызывается и в моем классе . Есть обратный вызов какой то или что еще?

Comment: класс не может отработать.

Comment: В андроиде очень много рефлексии. Классами наследующими от активити жонглируют кишки библиотеки и в двух словах объяснить сложно, да и не нужно. А вообще, посмотрите диаграмму жизненного цикла активити и не заморачивайтесь. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php  А вот как дорастете до уровня, когда и в байт-код посмотреть не страшно - тогда заморочтесь

Comment: rjhdby, я ведь не глубоко лезу, а всего лишь хочу понять почему onCreate вообще выполняется. Это я понял. но теперь не пойму почему в моем коде,который прикреплен к вопросу, сперва выполняется конструктор , а потом onCreate. А в коде Alex Krass наоборот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate` - это метод обратного вызова(callback), вызываемый в процессе жизненного цикла `Activity`.

Интерфейс, отвечающий за жизненный цикл `Activity` определен в классе `Application`

```
public interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState);
    void onActivityStarted(Activity activity);
    void onActivityResumed(Activity activity);
    void onActivityPaused(Activity activity);
    void onActivityStopped(Activity activity);
    void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState);
    void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity);
}
```

В этом же классе реализована логика управления `Activity` приложения.

Данный класс является этакой "входной точкой" вашего приложения и осуществляет всю оркестрацию активностей.

Answer (score 3):

В терминах С++ все функции в Java являются виртуальными - то есть всегда вызывается метод определенный в потомке, а не в родителе.

В конструкторе всегда вызывается сначала конструктор родителя.

Не знаю что тут еще добавить...

Comment: я все понял кроме одного. в коде товарища Alex Krass , выполняется у потомка сперва переопределенный метод, а потом конструктор. Если написать super. то выполняется метод в предке, потом метод в потомке и потом конструктор потомка. НО в коде что я привел в конце своего вопроса сперва выполняется конструктор , а потом onCreate. и так было во всех программках что я писал.. Почему у него выполняется сперва не конструктор ?

Answer (score 2):

Если что-то не понятно, достаточно просто написать тестовый пример и посмотреть, что и в каком порядке происходит.

```
class Rextester
{  
    static class Activity
    {
        public Activity()
        {
            System.out.println("Activity!");

            onCreate();
        }

        public void onCreate()
        {
            System.out.println("Activity.onCreate!");
        }
    }

    static class A extends Activity
    {
        public A()
        {
            System.out.println("A!");
        }

        public void onCreate()
        {
            System.out.println("A.onCreate!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A activity = new A();
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
Activity!
A.onCreate!
A!
```

Итого мы видим, что вызывается конструктор базового класса, который вызывает метод `onCreate();`. При это вызывается уже переопределенный `onCreate();` после которого вызывается второй конструктор уже нашего класса А.

И сразу становится ясно, зачем нужен `super.onCreate();`

Comment: что то в java какая то странная очередность вызова конструкторов (: вернее не вызова конструкторов, а что родительский вообще вызывается сам по себе.

Comment: teran, вот очередность  https://github.com/Javer-com-ua/WIKI/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-Java

Comment: из этой очередности видно, что родительскиий обязан вызваться, думаю не только в java так.

Comment: Alex Krass, выходит что если в момент когда выполняется блок кода в конструкторе родителя, обнаруживается что onCreate переопределен и этот метод не выполняется. Далее выполняется конструктор потомка и после переопределенный метод. Если в нем есть super то выполняется всё что есть в методе у родителя, а потом всё остальное что дописано ? так?

Comment: @Turalllb конструктор родителя  → переопределенный метод потомка → конструктор потомка. Если в переопределенном есть вызов super исходного, то он выполнится в обычном порядке следования инструкций → вы же можете написать super в любом месте переопределенной функции, а не только в начале или конце.

Comment: Alex Krass, почему в вашем коде  в классе потомка сперва выполняется  переопределенный метод, а потом конструктор, а в коде что я привел в вопросе наоборот ?

Comment: @Turalllb я понял, тогда возможно он вызывается самим фреймворком откуда-то еще после создания класса, а не в родителе. В документации [пишут что-то про "This method must be called from the main thread of your app"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)), но поскольку мои знания Java почти нулевые, что-то более конкретное я не подскажу. Посмотрите ответ rjhdby, но это уже не полиморфизм, а просто обратные вызовы.

Comment: Alex Krass, тогда выходит ваш ответ неверен. Но помог понять кое что о полиморфизме, чего я не знал. Верное оказалось мое предположение, что это метод обратного вызова. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Turalllb вероятно не только, но и далеко не везде. в php и delphi к примеру, родительский конструктор надо вызывать явно, и это дает большую свободу действий при разработке. в с# и c++ ситуация аналогична java